# How do I convert a binary file to size_t?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary, buffer, fstream

I'm trying to understand pointers and binary, but I'm stuck. I want to write a list containing 5 pieces of fruit to a binary file. So firstly I try to write (size_t) 5, then for each fruit piece the size of it and then the string itself.
This is what I got so far:

```
// Write
vector<string> fruit_list = {"Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Cherry", "Melon"};
ofstream fruits_out;
fruits_out.open("fruits.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
size_t fruit_total = fruit_list.size();
fruits_out.write((char*)&fruit_total, sizeof(fruit_total));
for (const string& fruit : fruit_list){
    size_t fruit_size = fruit.size();
    fruits_out.write((char*)&fruit_size, sizeof(fruit_size));
    fruits_out.write(&fruit.c_str()[0], fruit_size);
}
fruits_out.close();

// Read
ifstream fruits_in;
fruits_in.open ("fruits.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
char *buffer = new char;
fruits_in.read((char*)&buffer, sizeof(size_t));
cout << *buffer << endl;
```

I can't even read the first value.
Please help me no this matter, I'm stuck on it for ages.

Comment: You only allocated space for a single char.

Comment: A file is a stream of bytes. Before you write data to a file or read data from a file, you should document the precise stream of bytes you want to write and read. How many bytes will you write to store the size? What will the value of each byte be? I strongly urge you to do this before you write code -- it will make your life so much easier.

Comment: But I have to buffer to a char type first right?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the pointer that gets passed to `read()` must be created with `new`. This is not true. P.S. right, a "buffer to a char type". But there is a big difference between "a buffer of 1 char" and "a buffer of a billion chars". Both of them are a "buffer to a char type", but only one of them can be used to `read()` `size_t` worth of characters, without resulting in memory corruption.

Comment: Please place code in your post, not in the comment section.

Comment: Also, you explicitly wrote two items of data per fruit.  Yet on the read, you only try to read the fruit string.  Doesn't that seem unbalanced to you?  Shouldn't you be reading in two pieces of information?  This is not withstanding the erroneous `new char` you have in your code now.

Comment: Your binary file format code is dependent on platform specific characteristics, such as the `sizeof(size_t)` and platform endian-ness.  That's fine for a binary format that is tied to your platform, but if you want it to be cross-platform you will want to make your code platform agnostic.

Comment: BTW, pointers should not be written to a file.  There is no guarantee that the OS will place your program in the same location on every invocation.  There is no guarantee that the OS will give you the same data area on each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your writing code is fine (minus a lack of error handling, and there is no need to use `&c_str()[0]` when `c_str()` by itself will suffice).

However, your reading code is all wrong.  Not only are you allocating a `buffer` that is only 1 byte in size and then you try to read `sizeof(size_t)` number of bytes into it.  But worse, you are reading into stack space where the `buffer` variable is located, not into the dynamic memory that you allocated which `buffer` is pointing at!

Just like the writing code is passing a `size_t` by pointer to `ostream::write()`, you can also pass a `size_t` by pointer to `istream::read()` as well.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
std::ostream& writeSizeT(std::ostream &out, size_t value)
{
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));

    /* alternatively:
    uint64_t temp = htobe64(value); // or equivalent...
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
    */

    return out;
}

std::ostream& writeString(std::ostream &out, const std::string &value)
{
    size_t size = value.size();
    if ((writeSizeT(out, size)) && (size > 0)) {
        out.write(value.c_str(), size);
    }
    return out;
}

std::ostream& writeFruitList(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<std::string> &list)
{
    if (writeSizeT(out, list.size())) {
        for (const std::string &fruit : list){
            if (!writeString(out, fruit)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}

std::vector<std::string> fruit_list = {"Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Cherry", "Melon"};
std::ofstream fruits_out("fruits.bin", std::ios::binary);
writeFruitList(fruits_out, fruit_list);
fruits_out.close();
```

```cpp
std::istream& readSizeT(std::istream &in, size_t &value)
{
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));

    /* alternatively:
    uint64_t temp;
    if (in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(temp))) {
        temp = be64toh(temp); // or equivalent...
        value = static_cast<size_t>(temp);
    }
    */

    return in;
}

std::istream& readString(std::istream &in, std::string &value)
{
    value.clear();
    size_t size;
    if ((readSizeT(in, size)) && (size > 0)) {
        value.resize(size);
        in.read(&value[0]/*or: value.data()*/, size);
    }
    return in;
}

std::istream& readFruitList(std::istream &in, std::vector<std::string> &list)
{
    list.clear();
    size_t size;
    if (readSizeT(in, size)) {
        list.reserve(size);
        std::string fruit;
        for (size_t i = 0; (i < size) && (readString(in, fruit)); ++i){
            list.push_back(std::move(fruit));
        }
    }
    return in;
}

std::vector<std::string> fruit_list;
std::ifstream fruits_in("fruits.bin", std::ios::binary);
readFruitList(fruits_in, fruit_list);
fruits_out.close();

for (const auto &fruit: fruit_list) {
    std::cout << fruit << std::endl;
}
```